# Get User ID from ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface Web Service through Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, people-picker

I am using this webservice

```
/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser
```

to build an autocomplete solution for my SP app. The problem is, the service brings back almost all the details that I need about the user, except 1: the ID.

[image]

**The user ID**, or SID: the same ID SP lists populate in their people picker fields.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser
```

That's that true! Above end-point does not provide user or group `ID`. But it provides login name. From login name we can get the `ID`. Find a example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798407/SharePoint-REST-API-Get-User-Id-by-User-Name).

```
function GetUserId(userName) {
            /// change this prefix according to the environment. 
            /// In below sample, windows authentication is considered.
            var prefix = "i:0#.w|";
            /// get the site url
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
            /// add prefix, this needs to be changed based on scenario
            var accountName = prefix + userName;

            /// make an ajax call to get the site user
            $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + 
                    encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    ///popup user id received from site users.
                    alert("Received UserId" + data.d.Id);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        }
```

I do not like above end-point for building custom people picker. I like following end-point.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList
```

I have an article regarding that. Find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008871/Developing-Custom-Date-Picker-People-Picker-and-Ch)

```
function getPeoplePickerSuggestion(searchKey) {
    var userSearchSuggestionEndpoint = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?
        $select=Id,Name&$filter=substringof('" + searchKey + "',Name)";
    return baseSvc.getRequest(userSearchSuggestionEndpoint);
}
```

Comment: Except using the user information list does not guarantee you get the actual user unless you know the user has visited the site collection at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Atish for the answer. While we can get the ID through another web service call, Atish had provided a cleaner solution - which was to use:

```
var userSearchSuggestionEndpoint = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?
    $select=Id,Name&$filter=substringof('" + searchKey + "',Name)";
```

I tried and it works. Thanks again!